# Pass address parameter to base class pointer via constructors in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors, point-cloud-library

I am using a pointer of abstract type that is inherited from a base class.

Currently, each subclass must include the following behaviour in their constructor:

```
p = &f; //where p is the inherited pointer and f is the subclass filter
```

Naturally, I wish to move this behaviour up to the base class but I'm struggling to get this work. I'm not sure whether this is due how I am declaring types or if I need to change the implementation to reflect the movement of the behaviour (or something else!).

I've essentially tried to copy this line and call the base constructor through the subclass constructor:

```
//base.h
class Base {
    pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>* f;
    public:
        Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB> abs_filter);
};

//base.cpp
Base::Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB> abs_filter) { f = &abs_filter; }

//subclass.h
class Subclass: public Base {
    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGB> vg;
    public:
        Subclass(void);
};

//subclass.cpp
Subclass::Subclass(void): Base(vg) { }
```

This will not compile and produces the following error:

```
error: cannot declare parameter ‘abs_filter’ to be of abstract type ‘pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>’
```

I tried to take the address `pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB> &abs_filter` and change the method to `f = abs_filter;` but this also doesn't compile, reporting the following:

```
error: cannot convert ‘pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>’ to ‘pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>*’ in assignment Base::Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB> &abs_filter) { f = abs_filter; }
```

Where am I going wrong in what I am doing?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Just as a side note `abs_filter` is a *function local copy* of your `Filter` that only exists within the scope of your constructor. Storing a pointer to the address of that variable in `f` is going to leave you with a dangling pointer as soon as you leave the constructor.

Comment: If your member is a pointer then you should take a pointer.  That means `Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB> abs_filter); => Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>* abs_filter);`

Comment: Hi @CoryKramer, the only methods that use f are defined in the base class and are then inherited by the subclasses. Is this approach bad?

Comment: Hi @NathanOliver, so do I take in a pointer and then use the address of the pointer (`&pointer`) as done before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a function having a parameter passed by value, this is what happens

```
int myFun(myClass x) {
    // x exists only in this function
    // because is a copy of the argument passed to x
}
```

So change

```
Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB> abs_filter) { f = &abs_filter; }
```

to

```
Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>& abs_filter) { f = &abs_filter; }
```

Not to get a copy of it, to pass the value itself.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I was just wondering about the syntax here (I'm getting up to speed with it bit by bit) with the double use of `&`. If the parameter is `pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>& abs_filter` then I thought a variable `abs_filter` would be the value? Or is the variable `&abs_filter`?

Comment: You decleared `f` to be a pointer, so you have to reference `abs_filter` using `&` operator because it is a dereferenced object.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting f to a pointer to a local variable - that will not work (the abs_filter is a local copy of the vg-variable). Use one of the following:

```
   Base::Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>&abs_filter) { f = &abs_filter;}
   Base::Base(pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZRGB>*abs_filter) { f = abs_filter; }
```

(with corresponding change in classes).